Lens maker’s formula from parabolic approximation
I’m attempting to derive the lens maker’s formula for a thin or thick lens using the parabolic approximation.
I’m familiar with the other proof using the law of refraction and different angles.
The proof here involves studying first a planoconvex (half-spherical lens) and approximating the distance travelled through the lens as that of a parabola 1.
This follows from the paraxial (small angle approximation) for a sphere.
One then applies Fermat’s principle and argues that all paths through the lens must take equal time, that is, equal optical path length.
Therefore the path that travels up to a height h is equal to that travelled along the optical axis, so at a height of 0.
The derivation 2 argues the optical length in the lens (so the depth of the lens) is longer due to the refractive index of the lens (glass).
I agree with that point which would lead me to multiply the depth $d(h)$ by $n$.
However the attached proof claims that one needs to account for the difference between the refractive index in the glass and in air ($n=1$).
Therefore, in equation (2.3), it states the optical path length in the lens as $d(h)\times (n-1)$.
Why do we account for the difference in refractive indices?
That isn’t consistent with the definition of optical path length.
If we’re following that practice, why are we not doing so for the segments of the path in air (the first and second terms in the RHS of equation (2.3))?
How can this approach be generalised for a thick lens?
Do we need to approximate the distance travelled through the lens to higher order than the squared term( i.e. higher than the parabolic approximation)?
Thanks for any clarification.


